# play framework 1.x to render rich text

Tags: ckeditor, playframework-1.x

I am using Play framework 1.x and in one case, we are saving rich text data (I am currently using using ckeditor-JS on client side but am open to other suggestions e.g. markdown etc).  The data gets saved in the DB correctly i.e. with the HTML tags (unless I am misinterpreting how it ought to be saved).  I need to be able to render this content as HTML in my view - should I be looking to use the same library for handling the conversion or is there something in play framework (1.x) itself that I could possibly use.  Hope I explained the question properly and thanks in advance to any useful suggestions.

Comment: Conversion of what to what exactly. I can't tell if you want to render html for the editor to display, or if its for a page being edited. If you have raw html in your database and your just trying to render it on some page you can use [the raw() method in templates (groovy extensions)](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.5/cheatsheet/templates). Please post some code of what you've tried, and be more specific about what your looking to do. I may be able to give you a proper answer afterwards.

Comment: actually [this is a better reference for raw()](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.4/javaextensions)

Comment: Also you can use {verbatim} tag in your view to show data as is. Note that you should filter it before to prevent XSS attacks.

Comment: thanks yo everyone who commented/shared